# How to show progressbar until WP8 WebBrowser control loaded the URL?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a WebBrowser control and I want to show some url on this control. Until the webbrower loaded the page, I need to show some progressbar or animation.

Please help me, here's what I have:

**XAML:**

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <ProgressBar x:Name="progressbar" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webbrw" IsScriptEnabled="True"/>
</Grid>
```

**strong text**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
    //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    webbrw.LoadCompleted += webbrw_LoadCompleted;
    webbrw.Source = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/user/tseries");
}

void webbrw_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    progressbar.IsIndeterminate = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to *show* the bar while loading the page and *hide* it afterwards, you're using the wrong property. The `IsIndeterminate` property reports a generic process (true) or one based on a value (false). To hide the progressbar you should use:

```
progressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: how do i show progressbar? if i dont use IsIndeterminate ==true ( the dots are coming and go away)

Comment: i want to show some animation or something like progressbar :) , please help

Comment: Your XAML code is fine, but in the completed event of the browser use the line of code I gave.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using [`LoadCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property. Hope this solves your problem.

XAML Should be like:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressbar" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webbrw" IsScriptEnabled="True" LoadCompleted="yesLoaded"/>
```

C# for this;

```
    private void yesLoaded(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
        this.progressbar.IsIndeterminate = False;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Navigate method and catch Navigated event instead which triggers after the control navigates successfully. Check the MSDN reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser_events(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To handle every possible case, i had to register to these two WebBrowser events [LoadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [NavigationFailed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigationfailed%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

And of course, suspending the progress in each callback/handler with :

```
 progressbar.IsIndeterminate = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used OnNavigatedTo method to initialize the progressbar as shown below:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            progressbar.IsIndeterminate = true;
            //u can add other codes you need
        }
```

then check if the browser is fully loaded using LoadCompleted method as shown below:

```
 private void Browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            progressbar.IsIndeterminate = false;
        }
```

notice that the progressbar is a Name I gave to the ProgressBar on xaml and